# maven with gRPC

Tags: maven, grpc

I am trying to generate class files for gRPC. I have a proto file containing:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option java_multiple_files = true;
package grpc.greeting;

message HelloRequest {
  string firstName = 1;
  string  secondName = 2;
}

message HelloResponse {
  string greeting = 1;
}

service HelloService {
  rpc hello(HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse);
}
```

I have put proto file in a package grpc/protos.
I have added dependencies and plugin in pom.xml.

'mvn clean install' is successful, but I don't see any files generated.

Seems location of proto is wrong. So where do I need to place it? I also tried by placing it at project root.

Answer (score 0):

Proto files with Maven by default go to `src/main/protos`, not the same directory tree as your Java source files.

For an example, see how the [grpc-java examples project does it](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples).